# oozie : How to use oozie coodinator properties in corresponding workflow?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have a oozie job running as a coordinator which calls a worflow , in the coordinator there are some configuration properties which uses coordinator EL functions, like this -

${oozieAppDir}/copyLogs.wf.xml

```
   <configuration>
       <property>
           <name>filename3</name>
           <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -3, 'HOUR'), 'MM')}-${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -3, 'HOUR'), 'dd')}-${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -3, 'HOUR'), 'yyyy')}-${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -3, 'HOUR'), 'HH')}</value>
       </property>

  </configuration>
```

When an instance of this job is killed I want to rerun the workflow individually from the command line ,  but it gives error since its using properties defined in the coordinator and I can't add these properties in workflow since its using the coordinator EL functions, moreover I did not find the corresponding wf:EL functions , what is the best way to do this, I am basically interested in automating the failure of this workflow triggered by a coordinator. Please suggest the best way to go about it with minimal changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to the workflow during submission using `-D`

```
oozie job -oozie <oozie URL> -config <configFile> -Dnameofproperty=value  -submit
```

You can use `String wf:conf(String name)` function in your workflow to retrieve the value

Answer (score 1):

You need to define coordinator EL function/property in coordinator.xml and call that property in workflow.xml as:

**Coordinator**

```
<action>
      <workflow>
                <app-path>${workflowPath}</app-path>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                    <name>nominalTime</name>
                    <value>${coord:nominalTime()}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
      </workflow>
</action>
```

**Workflow(Hive example)**

```
<param>date=${nominalTime}</param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can use oozie expressions in configuration files?

When I need to run a workflow manually I define a property in a config file and submit that workflow to oozie.

configuration.properties :

```
filename3=/user/john/data.tsv
```

workflow.xml :

```
...
<property>
  <name>filename3</name>
  <value>${filename3}</value>
</property>
...
```

Then to run this workflow:

```
oozie -config configuration.properties -run
```